# How to normalize a dictionary of key and values pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My dictionary looks something like this: (has more data in the actual dictionary I'm working on)

`dictionary = {'101020': {'name': 'HJ', 'grades': [90, 80, 70]}, '101520': {'name': ABC', 'grades': [100, 40, 70]}}`

I want my dataframe to look like this:

```
code          name          grades
101020        HJ              90
101020        HJ              80
101020        HJ              70
101520        ABC             100
101520        ABC             40
101520        ABC             70
```

Currently I'm only able to get the name and data but not the code aka the key of the dictionary with this code:

```
vals = [val for val in dictionary.values())
df = pd.json_normalize(vals, 'grades', ['name']) I get the data without the key
print(df)
```

any help would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `explode` after using `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()`,

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary, orient='index') \
   .explode('grades') \
   .rename_axis('code') \
   .reset_index()

df
```

Output:

[image: output]